# JavaScript Determinant Calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm trying to make a matrix determinant calculator but I got stuck at some point. Could any one here point out to where the issue with my code is? would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
function det3x3(){
var mat[[],[],[]], i, j, sum, s;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
           s = i*3+j+1;
           mat[i][j] = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num" + s).value);
     }

sum = mat[0][0]*mat[1][1]*mat[2][2]+mat[1][0]*mat[2][1]*mat[0][3]+mat[2]
[0]*mat[0][1]*mat[1][2]-mat[0][2]*mat[1][1]*mat[2][0]-mat[1][2]*mat[2]
[1]*mat[0][0]-mat[2][2]*mat[0][1]*mat[1][0];

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=sum;
}
</script>
<body>
<input type="text" id="num1" value="0">
<input type="text" id="num2" value="0">
<input type="text" id="num3" value="0">
<br>
<input type="text" id="num4" value="0">
<input type="text" id="num5" value="0">
<input type="text" id="num6" value="0">
<br>
<input type="text" id="num7" value="0">
<input type="text" id="num8" value="0">
<input type="text" id="num9" value="0">

<br><br>

<button type="button" id="asd" onclick=”det3x3()">calculate</button>

<br><br>
result:
<span id="result"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lets start from `onclick="det3x3()"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the variable declaration:

```
var mat[[],[],[]]
```

should be:

```
var mat = [[],[],[]]
```

And you reference an array element that does not exist:

```
mat[0][3]
```

should be:

```
mat[0][2]
```

Finally, the HTML code has a bad curly quote `”`:

```
onclick=”det3x3()"
```

should be:

```
onclick="det3x3()"
```

Comment: @MaxZoom it was like 3am and I was up for over 24 hours. Mistakes happen. + it's not copied from anywhere. I typed it on a phone.

Comment: @trincot thanks mate. I fixed the bad curly and the array element after I posted this but just overlooked the define of the array. Helped a lot, much appreciated.